# how to buffer a raster cell using Visual Basic ArcObjects in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vb

I am new in visual basic, I have a question about creating a buffer zone based on a raster layer.

I have a raster layer named "Value_Raster", I have a textbox in the userform, I also create a tool button. In the mousemove event under this toolbutton, I want to create a buffer area that the origin is the raster cell value when I move my cursor on the cell, the buffer area can be a square (or rectangular) shape , when the sum of the raster values in the buffer zone is equal to the textbox value in the userform, the buffer will stop. finally the sum of the buffered area is displayed in the msgbox.

please help me out! thanks a lot.

Emma

Comment: This isn't very clear to me.  Are you wanting to grow a square on top of the current mouse location until the sum of the pixel values within that square reaches some value in the textbox?

Comment: yes, Exactly as you said, the square size is depending on the sum of the raster cell values, if the sum value reaches the textbox value, then the square stop growing.... hope it makes clearer. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned because it has had no activity for 18 months and its asker has not logged into the site for 9 months.  Consequently, I propose that it be closed.